# How to import correctly an Assembly created in SolidWorks into Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys!

I'm trying to import a 3D model of a Fanuc robot into Gazebo. I've already created the URDF using the sw_urdf_exporter
plugin obtaining the following result.
What's next?
I succeed in importing a single part like in this tutorial http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=import_mesh&cat=build_robot.
Do I have to follow a similar procedure?

[image: image description]

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13598/how-to-import-correctly-an-assembly-created-in-solidworks-into-gazebo/) by [nico_lauda](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2653/nico_lauda/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You'll need to create a model.config file (manifest.xml is deprecated) as shown in [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_robot&cat=build_robot). From there, you need to put it somewhere gazebo can find it. Either set GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH, or just put it in ~/.gazebo/models (I think that one works by default).

If you have further issues comment on this answer or update your question.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0